# $_POST method turns empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

Firstable, hello everyone. I have issue about the $_POST method, when I write this code block;

```
if (isset($_POST['menuduzenle'])) {

$menu_id=$_POST['menu_id']; //It didn't turn with value in mysql

$ayarguncelle=mysql_query("update menuler set menu_ad='".$_POST['menu_ad']."',menu_link='".$_POST['menu_link']."'where menu_id='$menu_id'");


if(mysql_affected_rows())
{

    header("Location:../menuleriduzenle.php?guncelleme=basarili&menu_id=$menu_id");
}else{

    header("Location:../menuleriduzenle.php?guncelleme=basarisiz&menu_id=$menu_id");}


}
```

menu_id turns emty, what I need to do for solve this?

and here it's html code

form

```
<form action="network/islem.php" method="POST">

     <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label>Menu Adı: </label>
            <input class="form-control" name="menu_ad" value="<?php echo $menucek['menu_ad']; ?>" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label>Menu Link: </label>
            <input class="form-control" name="menu_link" value="<?php echo $menucek['menu_link']; ?>" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit" name="menuduzenle" value="Edit Menu">
        </div>


    </form>
```

and

```
 <td><a href="menuleriduzenle.php?menu_id=<?php echo $menucek['menu_id'] ?>" type="submit"><button class="btn btn-primary col-md-12">Edit</button></a></td>
```

Comment: btw; you should add exit's after each header.

Comment: You're at risk of SQL injection. Don't use outdated APIs. I'll just wait for those copy-paste texts people use. I don't know where mine is xD xD

Comment: wait I'm adding html

Comment: `menu_id` comes from GET (link redirection), not from POST (form submission)

Comment: I tried but same

Comment: Anchor tags can't have `type="submit"`.

Comment: Why not have a hidden field with name `menu_id` in the form?

Comment: Fred, I tried GET method and it didn't work. Firstone how can I hidden field name? Can you give example?

Comment: ok I'm trying thanks for answer

Comment: Your input element needs a name like this: name='menuduzenle'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysql_error()` on the query. You will see errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not send any one input with name 'menu_id' on your from.

```
<form action="network/islem.php" method="POST">

     <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label>Menu Adı: </label>
            <input class="form-control" name="menu_ad" value="<?php echo $menucek['menu_ad']; ?>" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label>Menu Link: </label>
            <input class="form-control" name="menu_link" value="<?php echo $menucek['menu_link']; ?>" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit" name="menuduzenle" value="Edit Menu">
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="menu_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['menu_id'] ?>" />

    </form>
```

You input name "menu_ad" would be "menu_id" or fault other input with name "menu_id" on you sample.

Comment: It will be turn menu_name, so it not work edit: menu_ad = menu_name

Comment: I do already but thanks for much all of you. P.S: I do your sample and work